# AngularJS form data not stored in MySQL db

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, angularjs

In my AngularJS app, the data entered into the form are not stored in the MySQL database after hitting the submit button. An alert after successful form data submit however indicates that it is working.

Also, after hitting the submit button, I want the app to proceed to the next view (#/setup-step2) - however it remains at step1.

html partial (#/setup-step1):

```
<form ng-submit="submitForm1()">
Job title: <input type="text" name="jobtitle" ng-model="formData1.jobtitle">
Vacancy ID: <input type="text" name="vacancyid" ng-model="formData1.vacancyid">
<button type="submit" class="animatedbutton"> Proceed </button>
</form>
```

controller.js:

```
var ctr = angular.module('myApp.controller', []);
ctr.controller
('Step1Controller', ['$scope', '$routeParams', '$http', function($scope, $routeParams, $http){
 $scope.formData1 = {};
                        $scope.submitForm1 = function() {
                        $http({
                            method: 'POST',
                            url: 'php/setup-step1.php',
                            data: $.param($scope.formData1),
                            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
                        })
                            .success(function(data){
                                console.log(data);
                                alert("It worked");
                            })
                            .error(function(data) {
                                console.log(data);
                                alert("It didn't work");
                            })

                    }
}]);
```

setup-step1.php in folder /php:

```
<?php
include_once('db.php');
// Check connection
if(mysqli_connect_errno())
  {echo '<p>Connection to MySQL server failed: '.mysqli_connect_error().'</p>';}
else
  {echo '<p>Connection to MySQL server successful.</p>';}

$_POST = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);

if (empty($_POST['jobtitle'])) 
   {$errors['jobtitle'] = 'Job title is required.';}
else {
// Escape user inputs for security
   $jobtitle = $_POST['jobtitle'];
   $vacancyid = $_POST['vacancyid'];
   $data = "INSERT INTO campaign (Job_title, Job_id) VALUES ('$jobtitle','$vacancyid')";mysql_query("INSERT INTO campaign (Job_title, Job_id) VALUES ('$jobtitle', '$vacancyid')");}

if ($connect->query($data) === TRUE) 
   {$conn->close();} 
else 
   {echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;}

exit();
?>
```

Comment: do you see anything in the chrome console? what is in the server log? mysql log?

Comment: added the console log to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer myself. The problem was incorrect php and mysql syntax. Updated the code the way it works now.

Answer (score 0):

First,
Be sure that you enable the cors before performing any request to the server.When you are working with angularjs this usually means that you are making cors requests to the server.If you didn't enable cors option you cannot call any method from the server since it is not allowed.

Second, 
just keep php code inside your setup-step1.php.You don't need any html code there since it will return result of your requet only.

Third,
As I know you cannot change location of the webpage from erver because server domin and website domains are different.You need to redirect the user to another page in angularjs. You can find the ways of redirecting in angularjs by using $location or $state.

Comment: Tbh I have never heard of cors before. Does this still apply if another simple html form (no angularjs or whatsoever) on the same server successfully performs a php request and stores the data in a MySQL db?

Comment: if they are on the same server no. Cors is only applied if the server side and client side are located in separate domains.